# having issue appending li on to ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I am creating an `ul` and adding `li` to it with data in it using jquery `append` function. Inside this `append` function I am calling another function to parse more xml data and add it to the `ul`. But this function displays only `[object Object]`. Whereas when I `console.log(li)` inside `func()` function then it displays the correct `li`.

here is my code

```
container.append(
            '<ul>'
                + '<li>'
                    + '<h4 class="title stitle">' + from 
                        + '<section><span class="subtitle">' + routeTime + ' mins    ' + routeDist + ' km</span></section><br>'
                    + '</h4>'
                    + '<ul class="contents">'
                        + '<li>' + '<img src="' + walk + '" />' + '</li>'
                        + '<li>' + '<span class="">' + startTime + '   ' + distance + ' km</li>'
                        + func(lines) //<-- function call here
                    + '</ul>'
                + '</li>' +
            '</ul>'
            );
```

here is the func function code

```
func = function (lines) {
    var li = $('<li></li>');

    lines.each(function () {
        var stopel          = $(this),
            busCode         = stopel.attr('code').slice(1,4),
            stops           = stopel.find('STOP');

        li.append('<img src="' + bus + '" />')
        .append('<span>' + busCode + '</span>')
        .append('<section class="clear"></section>');

        stops.each(function() {
            var el2         = $(this).find('NAME'),
                deptime     = $(this).find('DEPARTURE');
            li.append('<p class="stop">' + deptime.attr('time') + '   ' + el2.attr('val') + '</p>');
        });
        li.append('<p class="last"></p>');
    });
    console.log(li);
    return li;
}
```

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function returns a jQuery object. And when you are using the `+` operator on this object, you are using it as a string. So an attempt is made to convert it to a string, with the result of `[object Object]`.

The jQuery object has a method called [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which returns the HTML content of that jQuery object as a string - which you can safely use in the concatenation. In your case though, you would need an `.outerHtml()` method, which does not exist in jQuery, but you could add it (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)). Alternatively you could simply use the DOM (not jQuery) `.outerHTML` property, Firefox used to not support it, but they now do (from version 11, correct me if I'm wrong).

You can call the method on the return value of the `func` like this:

```
...
+ '<li>' + '<span class="">' + startTime + '   ' + distance + ' km</li>'
+ func(lines).outerHtml() //<-- function call here
+ '</ul>'
...
```

Or if you want the DOM way:

```
+ func(lines).get(0).outerHtml //<-- function call here
```

---

*Quick suggestion: you should use a templating solution like Mustache (my preference), Handlebars, etc. Creating HTML by concatenating strings in Javascript is ugly, hard to maintain and violates the rule of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). When you try one of these libraries, you will wonder how could you live without it.*

Comment: I did your way but now it does not concatenate the `li` but only the contents inside `li`. How can I make to so that the `li` including its content gets attached?

Comment: @x4f4r Hm, that's true. This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: @x4f4r Updated my answer to address your problem.

Comment: yep that link helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do 
`var li = $("<li></li>")`, you are passing a reference to instance of an List Object created for the DOM. You are manipulating this object and hence you are getting the output as [object Object] whereas in the Console you are seeing the HTML for that Object.

You should stringify the li object reference or use it in $.html(li) or li.html();

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the jQuery object, but looks like you want the HTML.

Try this at the end of your function:

```
return li.outerHTML;
```